# Unknown validator location validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I am working on my very first rails app so please pardon me if the answer is obvious.

My userlocation model looks like this

```
class UserLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :uid, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => "uid"
 has_one :current_location, :class_name => Location, :foreign_key =>   "city"
 has_one :destination, :class_name => Location, :foreign_key => "city"
 validates :user, presence: true
end
```

When I try to put something into this model I get the said error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `class_name` option should be a string, not a class.

Try using `:class_name => "User"` and `:class_name => "Location"` in your associations.

See examples on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html